# Python memory leak with strings

Tags: python, memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Here's an extremely simple example that's causing me endless grief:

```
import gc
def test(str1, str2):
    a = str1
    b = str2
    #del a 
    #del b
    #gc.collect()


for i in range(10000000000):
    test('\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', '\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t')
```

<s>If I remove the `del`'s and the `gc.collect`</s>, memory goes up forever at about 5MB a second on my system. I'm using Python 3.6.5 with Visual Studio. Is there some facet of Python I'm missing? I'm relatively new to the language.

Edit: It looks like the gc made it so slow I couldn't see if memory was going up or not. It still goes up very fast without it.

Comment: "goes up forever at about 5MB a second", even after terminating script?

Comment: Garbage collection does not start immediately if the function is left but periodically. Of course the GC must get some time to be triggered. I don't know the exact rules when the GC is supposed to run but the behavior you are describing (increasing memory) looks just normal to me.

Comment: Read [this](https://rushter.com/blog/python-garbage-collector/).

Comment: @Sraw Not after terminating, no.

Comment: @Florian M.The memory allocation by the program continues into infinity. The reason I noticed it in the first place is it ate up all my desktops memory and caused some other things to crash.

Comment: Citing from BurhanKhalid's link: "Unlike the reference counting, the cyclic GC does not work in real-time and runs periodically. To reduce the frequency of GC calls and pauses CPython uses various heuristics."

Comment: Running exactly the above on 3.6.4 64bit via PyCharm under Windows. With and without the `del()` and GC calls the process consumes a steady 5.600K memory. Do you always start this from VS or did you also try to run it from the shell once?

Comment: @shmee Weirdly enough, this example works fine when I call it from the shell but my full program does not and still eats memory (albeit at a slower rate).

Comment: OK, then at least the example shows no evidence of a memory leak on itself. Could you possibly come up with a MCVE from your code that shows your observed behavior when called from the shell? Maybe by trying to create such an MCVE you already identify the cuplrit.

Comment: @shmee Thanks, I'll definitely keep trying to do that, that's what I though I'd done here but apparently not.

Comment: @shmee Actually, the memory is freed eventually when run from the shell despite steadily rising. Thanks so much! I've spent way too much time on this.

Comment: @FlorianM. actually, here the `gc` is irrelevant. CPython uses reference counting. As soon as the reference count gets to zero, the memory of the object is released. the `gc` in that module is only their to take care of reference cycles. This, of course, doesn't apply in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @shmee, It looks like this was caused by Visual Studio itself as when the above code is run from the shell I don't have the same memory issue with runaway memory consumption.

Comment: yes, same issue. I am 100% sure my local variable in my loop wont be alive outside the loop. But when running in VS Code, the memory can goes up the 10+ GB, until it raises Memory Error. (My for loop runs for thousands of times.
And it just consumes 60MB if ran in Windows cmd.
The solution to VS Code is press Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F12 TWICE, to FORCE Garbage Collection. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-studio-performance-tips-and-tricks?view=vs-2017